# Are there some studies which measure the level of politicization of courts in a trans-Atlantic perspective?

Tags: united-states, european-union, political-theory, canada, judiciary

It's easy enough to find a Europe-only comparative perspective on the politicization of the judiciary, e.g. [Werkmann (2017)](https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/bitstream/handle/1887/53207/Werkman%2C%20Caroline-s1656023-ReMa%20Thesis%20POWE-2017.pdf?sequence=1):

> [image]
>
> The authors measured the level of politicization in each
> country with the Index of Party Patronage (IPP) which is calculated by using the median
> values for the range and depth of patronage in nine policy areas (i.e. Economy, Finance,
> Judiciary, Media, Military and Police, Foreign Service, Culture and Education, Health Care,
> and Regional and Local Administration) and three institutional types (i.e. ministerial
> departments, non-departmental agencies and commissions, and executing institutions). For the
> purpose of this study, the IPP is disaggregated to single out the level of politicization in the
> area of interest, i.e. the judiciary. The IPP ranges from 0, corresponding to complete absence
> of patronage practices, to 1 which indicates a full overlap of party and the state. Intermediate
> values are interpreted as follows. In general, a score of around 0.65 indicates that parties exert
> control over appointments in most institutions at all levels of the administration, a score of
> approximately 0.4 corresponds to partisan appointments in most institutions but only at top
> and middle levels, whereas a score of 0.1 means that party patronage occurs in a limited
> number of institutions and only at the top level. In the context of this study, a value of 0.4 thus
> translates to political appointments to top-level positions in the judiciary such as the chairman
> of court or senior judges, as well as middle positions in most of the national courts and the
> national ministry of justice. Scores on the bottom of the scale indicate that political parties are
> mostly uninvolved in the appointments to the judiciary

(You may or may not agree with this, and other studies [with different methodology] may have different results). What I want to ask here (with some relation to [a recent question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/34257/why-is-the-u-s-supreme-court-so-politicised)): are there trans-Atlantic studies measuring/comparing the level of politicization of the judiciary in most Western (or even OECD) democracies?

Comment: Interesting that German is on top here, if I'm not mistaken, the German constitutional court is quite powerful.

Comment: @gerrit Perhaps that level of power correlates directly with the level of politicisation. After all, the US Supreme Court is very powerful and very politicised (though I can't back that up with a studt that compares it directly with European courts, else I would be posting an answer). While the UK Supreme Court is not powerful, and Britain has one of the least politicised judiciaries.